# not related lines in big resoultion screen

Tags: css, html, explorer

I tried go to holdings in this website
http://eurocom.richkid.co.il/en/home/a/main/#holdingsPage

and when click on Amos for example I saw unrelated lines.

why it is?

(css reason)

this is what happened:
http://jpg.co.il/view/55d31c7298f95.png/
(explorer11)

thanks.

Comment: this website cannot be viewed well on internet explorer, IE is just crap, why are you using IE when you have many other and 1000% extra powerful alternatives.

Comment: because the customer wants

Comment: Oh wait, "Space Communications Ltd". That wasn't very clear. Anyway, I don't see the extra lines with IE11; it looks just like other browsers.